# Get OKTA SAML assertion via API

Tags: saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

How do I get OKTA SAML assertion via API. I have integrated OKTA as sso provider with PureCloud application. Now I want to authenticate user via OKTA.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried with this help article for configuring OKTA-PureCloud SSO Authentication. 
https://help.mypurecloud.com/articles/add-okta-as-a-single-sign-on-provider/

What it basically does is it sets OKTA as the identity provider for PureCloud application. So any user trying to login to purecloud website will automatically be redirected to OKTA login page.

Comment: Thanks Gokhale, I have configured OKTA as SSO provider for PureCloud and is working as expected. My concern is I want to authenticate PureCloud user via API through OKTA SAML Response that accepts credentials. And this SAML Response will be passed to PureCLoud API for getting access Token